# Removing lines from a file already present in another file

Tags: unix, scripting, hp-ux

I have 2 files : One.lst and Two.lst.

One.lst contains :

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

Two.lst contains :

```
c
d
```

I need One.lst to contain only a,b,e ie removing the lines from One.lst that are already present in Two.lst.

So,the updated One.lst will be :

```
a
b
e
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for `grep`:

```
$ grep -vf Two.lst One.lst
a
b
e
```

To update the file with the content, do:

```
grep -vf Two.lst One.lst > temp_file && mv temp_file One.lst
```

---

From `man grep`:

> **-f FILE**, --file=FILE
>
> Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.
>
> **-v**, --invert-match
>
> Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.

Comment: No, you cannot redirect `grep`'s output to one of the files that is involved in the operation. Otherwise you will get an error like "grep: input file ‘One.lst’ is also the output"

Comment: The files that i have(One.lst and Two.lst) are pretty huge in size and i already have space issues.So,i cannot create another temp_file.Is there any other way?

Comment: Well you can maybe loop through `Two.lst` and for every line, delete it from `One.lst` with `sed -i`. It won't require temp files, but will be very unefficient.

Comment: Yes,that would be inefficient.Anyway,i will try with your approach only. Thanks a lot for the help. Highly appreciated.